# Texture related memory leak in XNA 4.0 / C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xna, directx, texture2d

I found a memory leak in my XNA 4.0 application written in C#. The program needs to run for a long time (days) but it runs out of memory over the course of several hours and crashes. Opening Task Manager and watching the memory footprint, every second another 20-30 KB of memory is allocated to my program until it runs out. I believe the memory leak occurs when I set the `BasicEffect.Texture` property because that is the statement that finally throws the `OutOfMemory` exception.

The program has around 300 large (512px) textures stored in memory as Texture2D objects. The textures are not square or even powers of 2 - e.g. can be 512x431 - one side is always 512px. These objects are created only at initialization, so I am fairly confident it is not caused by creating/destroying Texture2D objects dynamically. Some interface elements create their own textures, but only ever in a constructor, and these interface elements are never removed from the program.

I am rendering texture mapped triangles. Before each object is rendered with triangles, I set the `BasicEffect.Texture` property to the already created `Texture2D` object and the `BasicEffect.TextureEnabled` property to `true`. I apply the `BasicEffect` in between each of these calls with `BasicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply()`  - I'm aware that I'm calling `Apply()` twice as much as I should, but the code is wrapped inside of a helper class that calls `Apply()` whenever any property of `BasicEffect` changes.

I am using a single `BasicEffect` class for the entire application and I change its properties and call `Apply()` any time I render an object.

First, could it be that changing the `BasicEffect.Texture` property and calling `Apply()` so many times is leaking memory?
Second, is this the proper way to render triangles with different textures? E.g. using a single `BasicEffect` and updating its properties?

This code is taken from a helper class so I've removed all the fluff and only included the pertinent XNA calls:

```
//single BasicEffect object for entire application
BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect(graphicsDevice);

// loaded from file at initialization (before any Draw() is called)
Texture2D texture1 = new Texture2D("image1.jpg");
Texture2D texture2 = new Texture2D("image2.jpg");

// render object 1
if(effect.Texture != texture1) // effect.Texture eventually throws OutOfMemory exception
    effect.Texture = texture1;
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
effect.TextureEnabled = true;
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
graphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices1, 0, numVertices1, indices1, 0, numTriangles1);

// render object 2
if(effect.Texture != texture2)
    effect.Texture = texture2;
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
effect.TextureEnabled = true;
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
graphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices2, 0, numVertices2, indices2, 0, numTriangles2);
```

It's an XNA application, so 60 times per second I call my Draw method, which renders all my various interface elements. This means that I could be drawing between 100-200 textures per frame, and the more textures I draw, the faster I run out of memory, even though I am not calling `new` anywhere in the update/draw loops. I am more experienced with OpenGL than DirectX, so clearly something is happening behind the scenes that is creating unmanaged memory I'm not aware of.

Comment: Can you give project for visual studio with this problem? I have few ideas for trying solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately the project is research-based, and too large to extract a small chunk, so I can't distribute it.

Comment: Don't try to guess what's going on here.  Learn to use the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273) tool.  It will tell you exactly what is causing memory to be allocated.

Comment: Actually, your code looks fine. That's how I would go about it, too. The problem might be deep within XNA. If you can't find a solution, you can try to recreate the effect every now and then. Definitely not a good solution, but if it works...

Comment: as Cole Campbell says; Use the CLR profiler. I want to add that loading textures from file like that means you have to dispose them yourself. If you don't, and you load them several times, you will run into OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion to you that I can come up with, is to group your textures into atlases rather than one by one. It will speed up your rendering time and reduce the load on the GPU, provided that you are rendering a massive amount of textures per frame. The reason for this, is because the GPU will not have to swap textures to render so often which is an expensive operation. I am using my knowledge of OpenGL, but my guess is that XNA is based on DirectX and I am assuming they load textures in a similar manner (unless you are using Monogame which lets you use OpenGL)

That said, you did not provide very much information. The memory leak can be coming from the texture switching, but it can also be coming from somewhere else. Most of your memory is occupied with textures, which is probably why you are getting a crash there rather than somewhere else. I am guessing a few things are happening here:

- The garbage collector is not working fast enough to pick up all the RAM being allocated inside the rendering functions
- You have a memory leak somewhere else in your code, and it is showing up here instead

Once again, it is difficult to figure out what is on here provided how little I know about your code. But to my best ability, I have a few suggestions for you:

- Run through your code and look at how you are referecing things. Make sure that you don't have any temporary references inside of classes and structs. If you use something and pass it around to difference classes and consider it later as "discarded", there is good chance that someone is still holding onto that object, preventing it from being deleted
- Do a search for all the "new" keywords you have in the solution. If you have something that constantly gets using the "new" keyword, this can be a huge memory leak as it's creating a massive ammount of objects in the heap. The garbage collector SHOULD be picking them up, but I wouldn't say I trust the garbage collector very much. Worst case that garbage collector is not coming around often enough to deal with this memory leak.
- Find ways to reduce the sizes of textures. Atlasing is a solution that will reduce the overhead of packaging each texture in it's own Texture2D. This can be a bit more work because you will have to work in a system of swapping textures from the same file, but in your case that very well maybe worth it.
- *If you are convinced that there is an issue within XNA, try a different implementation called Monogame. It follows the exact same structure as XNA but is maintained by a community. As a result, the guts of the libraries you are using have been rewritten and there is a good chance that whatever is destroying your heap has been fixed.*

My advice to you? If you are really familiar with OpenGL and what you are doing is fairly simple, then I would check out OpenTK. it is a thin linker layer that takes OpenGL and "ports" it into C#. All the commands are the exact same and you have the flexibility of using the entire .NET library for all the extra fluff.

I hope this helps!